# No GTK settings in Opensuse 13.2, KDE Plasma 5

Tags: kde, opensuse, gtk, plasma

I remember that in KDE 4 (at least in Kubuntu) and also in other KDE 5 environments I tested, there were some appearance settings for GTK applications.

I have installed Opensuse 13.2 with Xfce desktop and then added KDE5. I see no GTK options under settings.

.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing kde-gtk-config (or as it is called in SUSE).